# Movie about frozen person who wakes up in the future

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I know that there are lots of movies out there about frozen people waking up in the future, but I have looked far and wide for this and haven't been able to find it.

(This *may* be a novel, but I remember seeing a movie poster for it, so it's probably a movie)

So I believe the main character is a funky-looking white guy in his 20s-30s with big glasses. He is frozen, then wakes up in the future where everyone is required to have some kind of ID (a chip or a code, perhaps?). This man, however, being from the far past, does not have an ID and immediately becomes the leader of a group who is rebelling against the ID system.

(This picture MAY be from the movie; I reverse-image searched this all over the place but can't find any source for it. Also I haven't watched the movie, this person just looks somewhat like the man from the poster.)

[image: could be :/]

The movie poster, I believe, has the main character with a dazed face on sitting in an umbrella-chair holding a woman.

This movie is probably anywhere from the 70's to the 90's, the movie poster looked 80's style though.

I never watched the movie, but I read a summary of the events somewhere and couldn't find it. The poster may have been from another movie.

Comment: That photo is from Austen Powers which doesn't have a plot similar the the one described above, hope you get an answer!

Comment: @MaxAstall That's helpful! Do you mind telling me the plot of the Austen Powers episode that has the scene above? Is he being frozen?

Comment: This image is from one of Austin powers movies. As for your description, it's closer to "Idiocracy", but can't tell without enough details.

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! We have a minimum requirement for ID questions on this site.  What language was it in? Was it an American production, or from a different country? Was it real life or animated? Was it in color? We'll need answers to these questions to help us track down an answer to this question.  If you have this information, please edit it into your question.

Comment: @DForck42 The Q contains plenty of details and then some, if you ask me.

Comment: @BeardWix he gets cryogenically frozen and then un-frozen (defrosted?) when his arch nemesis Dr. Evil comes back to earth. I'm not entirely sure which AP movie this is, the second I assume

Comment: The beginning of your description is very similar to the the *Futurama* episode *Space Pilot 3000*.

Comment: The [first Austin Powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austin_Powers:_International_Man_of_Mystery):  "Dr. Evil escapes in a space rocket disguised as a Big Boy statue, and cryogenically freezes himself. Powers volunteers to be placed into cryostasis in case Dr. Evil returns in the future."  Powers is frozen in the 1960s and returns in the 1990s.  So the beginning of the movie was set in the past and the bulk of the movie was set in the (then) present.

Comment: If you have a picture and don't know where it comes from, you can simply upload it (or drag-and-drop) to https://images.google.com It analyzes the picture and its metadata. For the above example, it returns `austin powers waking up`

Comment: @EricDuminil I said up there that I reverse-image searched the photo, it only turned up lists of "movie characters that were frozen" and the like.

Comment: @BeardWix: Google might have found your question and updated the metadata linked to this picture in the meantime.

Comment: @alroc Yup, that's it. They're describing Futurama.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Pretty sure you're looking for Woody Allen's comedy [**Sleeper**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070707/combined) from 1973.

> Miles, a nebbishy clarinet player who also runs a health food store in NYC's Greenwich Village, is cryogenically frozen, and brought back - 200 years in the future, by anti-government radicals in order to assist them in their attempt to overthrow the oppressive government. When he goes off on his own, he begins to explore this brave new world, which has Orgasmatron booths to replace sex and confessional robots.

Allen stars, has big glasses, can help the rebels because he isn't registered, and the movie's poster fits your description (see below). [Here's the trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FRLeYaut3o).

[image]

Comment: Ah, those classic actors Woody Diane and Allen Keaton!

Answer (score 0):

The 1960s BBC TV series Adam Adamant had a plot a bit like this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Adamant_Lives!

The Wikipedia article claims this as inspiration for the Austin Powers film.